# Is the intermediate value theorem saying that if $f$ is continuous on some interval, then it is a surjective function?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Is the Intermediate Value Theorem basically saying that if a function is continuous on an interval, then the function is surjective?

The formal definition states something to the effect of "any value in the domain will map to a value in the range", unless I misunderstand it. So, since we're mapping from $[a,b] \to [f(a), f(b)]$, the range is made up of the images of the values in the domain, that is, the range is the codomain.

My understanding of a surjective function is one in which $\forall x\in D, f(x)\in C$, where $f:D\to C$.

Or an I horribly mistaken? Ha ha

Comment: The intermediate value theorem is for functions $[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb R$. It tells us the range of such functions is an interval. The codomain is not $[f(a),f(b)]$.

Comment: The function $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb R$ need not to be surjective. A function between any two sets always trivially surjects onto its image. As the above commentator states, the intermediate function theorem tells us about the *nature* of such image, provided that the domain is an interval.

Comment: Surjectivity goes the other way round: $\forall x\in C\exists x\in D f(x)=C.$

Comment: Thanks, it's been a while since I've looked at it and I wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It means its image is an interval, but that's all: for instance, look at the constant function $f\colon [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) =1 $ for all $x\in[0,1]$.

It is continuous, and the IVT applies. But it is definitely not surjective... its image is the (trivial) interval $\{1\}$. Surjectivity would ask that $\forall y \in C=\mathbb{R}$, there exists $x\in D=[0,1]$ such that $f(x)=y$.

Comment: Is the fact that its image is an interval part of the proof of the theorem?

Comment: That's exactly what the theorem proves, actually. For any two points $ \alpha \leq \beta$ in the image of $f$, any point $ \gamma\in(\alpha,\beta)$ also belongs to the image of $f$.

Comment: Thanks, this all answered my question.

Answer (score 0):

Let $I$ be the domain of $f$. If we restrict the co-domain to the image $f[I]$, that is consider $f^*: I \to f[I]$ given by $f^*(x) = f(x)$, then $f^*$ is surjective since a function trivially surjects onto its image.